# Can't order query correctly

Tags: sql, join, db2, left-join

A while ago I requested help to code a LEFT JOIN filtering in a particular way that the result postition the desired value in the first row.

[Need to retrieve table's last inserted/updated record with some exclusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370611/need-to-retrieve-tables-last-inserted-updated-record-with-some-exclusions)

The thing now is that there are many cases which are mixing data. The scenario is that on the same table we have 2 values that we need to organize on different columns. The PO_ID is unique, but can have 1 or more values on the other tables, and for this particular case 1 PO_ID has 3 SHIP_ID_CUS values. We only need 1 PO_ID per row (no duplicates) that is way we used the MAX() and GROUP BY.

Here is a piece of the code that I think cause issues.

```
select
z.po_id,
max(scdc.ship_id) as ship_id_cdc,
max(lscdc.ship_evnt_cd) as last_event_cdc,
max(lscdc.ship_evnt_tms) as event_tms_cdc,
max(scus.SHIP_ID) as ship_id_cus, 
max(lscus.ship_evnt_cd) as last_event_cus,
max(lscus.ship_evnt_tms) as event_tms_cus

from TABLE.A z
left join (select distinct po_id, iltc.ship_id, s.ship_to_loc_code from TABLE.B iltc inner join TABLE.C s on iltc.ship_id=s.ship_id and iltc.ship_to_loc_code=s.ship_to_loc_code and s.ship_to_ctry<>'   ') AS A ON z.po_id = a.po_id
left JOIN TABLE.C scus ON A.SHIP_ID = scus.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scus.loc_type = 'CUS' AND DAYS(scus.shipment_tms)+10 >= DAYS(z.ship_tms)
left JOIN TABLE.C scdc ON A.SHIP_ID = scdc.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scdc.loc_type = 'CDC' AND DAYS(scdc.shipment_tms)+10 >= DAYS(z.ship_tms)

left join 

(    select ship_id_856, ship_to_loc_cd856, ship_evnt_cd, ship_evnt_tms, carr_tracking_num, event_srv_lvl
            ,        row_number() over(partition by ship_id order by updt_job_tms desc) as RN
            FROM     TABLE.D
         WHERE LEFT(ship_evnt_cd, 1) <> '9') lscus
ON        lscus.ship_id_856=scus.ship_id and scus.ship_to_loc_code=lscus.ship_to_loc_cd856 and lscus.rn = 1

left join 

(    select ship_id_856, ship_to_loc_cd856, ship_evnt_cd, ship_evnt_tms, carr_tracking_num, event_srv_lvl
           ,        row_number() over(partition by ship_id order by updt_job_tms desc) as RN
            FROM     TABLE.D
         WHERE LEFT(ship_evnt_cd, 1) <> '9') lscdc
ON        lscdc.ship_id_856=scdc.ship_id and lscdc.ship_to_loc_cd856=scdc.ship_to_loc_code and lscdc.rn = 1

WHERE
z.po_id = 'T1DLDC'
GROUP BY z.po_id
```

By searching that condition we get the following result

[image]

The problem is that if we search directly on the TABLE.D, the last event that we need (with last update record tms) is another one (X1) and somehow the date is incorrect.

[image]

What is even more weird, is that if we search for the ship_id_cus on the original query, we get the correct code but still with a wrong date...

```
WHERE
--z.po_id = 'T1DLDC'
scus.ship_id = 'D30980'
GROUP BY z.po_id
```

[image]

I tried other logic changes like modifying the left joins to search on a subquery.

```
left JOIN ( select * from TABLE.C order by updt_job_tms desc) scus ON A.SHIP_ID = scus.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scus.loc_type = 'CUS' AND DAYS(scus.shipment_tms)+10 >= DAYS(z.ship_tms)
```

But this is also giving the same exact results by searching either by po_id or ship_id_cus

Any ideas or comment will be much appreciated.

Thanks

------------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------

Adding the result of the LEFT JOIN with the row_partition() including all the ship_id_cus for that po_id, and all the codes with the tms. None match here.

[image]

Based on all these, it should be the last ship_id_cus with X1 event/tms. If we exclude also the ones starting with 9, we would get the following result.

[image]

(I am not applying here ordering by ship_id_cus, which already described before that did not work either the way I implemented)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would make it easier to assist!

Comment: Hi @jarlh, if you refer to the code itself, you can see the results there with those pieces. In fact, original query is 223 lines of code. Please let me know what is not understood and I could try to rephrase. Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned that you got an unexpected date/timestamp. One way to narrow it down might be to find the row with that value and try to work out how it managed to get its way into the result set.

Comment: Updated post @jackic23. Hope it helps! Thanks

Comment: @JuanIgnacioDurante It's hard to understand what and why you do with such a complex select statement. It would be good enough if you schematically provided a set of tables you use with sample data, describe the relations between these tables, and provide the result desired. If you have some intermediate result sets, which you get as results of applying some joins/filters, then provide them as tables as well to hide some non-significant details for the final result.

Comment: what makes `lscus` different from `scus`? Could that be flattened out? Maybe the overlap there is causing something strange. From the looks of the query It doesn't seem to be introducing rows that don't exist in TABLE.D

Comment: Hi @jackic23 scus at ship id entity and lscus is at ship id events level. A ship id can have 1 or more events. Those events can also be repeated. Furthermore, the timestamps of the events can be updated. That is why the idea is to get the last event that arrives, every time the query runs. Hope it clarified the concern!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table: TBL1

```
ID     APPROVED APPROVER DATE_APPROVED
====== ======== ======== =============
ABC    Y        JOE      2019-01-13
ABC    N        ZACK     2018-12-23
ABC    N        SUE      2019-02-23
```

And you do SQL:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(APPROVED) AS APPROVAL
,MAX(APPROVER) AS APPROVED_BY , MAX(DATE_APPROVED) AS APPROVED_ON
FROM TBL1 GROUP BY ID
```

you will get result:

```
ID     APPROVAL APPROVED_BY APPROVED_ON
====== ======== =========== =============
ABC    Y        ZACK        2019-02-23
```

which is correct to the code but is NOT what you want

Try the following:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.APPROVED, T1.APPROVER, T1.DATE_APPROVED
FROM TBL1 AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(DATE_APPROVED) AS APPROVED_ON
FROM TBL1 GROUP BY ID
) AS T2
ON T1.ID =T2.ID
AND T1.DATE_APPROVED = T2.APPROVED_ON
```

Result:

```
ID     APPROVED APPROVER DATE_APPROVED
====== ======== ======== =============
ABC    N        SUE      2019-02-23
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. I tried applying max() and group by to subquery but I can't get the desired result still. Just a clarification, the id (in my case po_id) is from source table 1 but all the rest comes from table 3 and 4 so I am not sure if it follows your logic. If you could please review this statement and check the logic again, it will be helpful to rule out choises. Thanks again!

Comment: I was talking about the principle. Doesn't matter if it is a single table or multiple joined tables. You may also want to use the WITH statement (also known as Common Table Elements) to make your code readable and easy to maintain